# Why couldn't the extra Rangers be revived?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Game of Thrones Season 7 episode 6, some extra Rangers in a small party are killed. Thoros has revived the dead in the past using magic. Given that the mission was really important, and they only had a small party, why didn't he attempt to revive the extra Rangers after the encounter with the Polar Bear? In earlier episodes, we have seen Thoros revive someone else, and it only took a few seconds.

Comment: This title is meaningless.

Comment: Still meaningless

Comment: Why not use his name?

Comment: Nothing wrong with naming the character in the title here.

Comment: I've attempted to make it as non-spoilery as possible while making it clear.

Answer (score 14):

Thoros can't just bring anyone back. He makes this clear in a conversation with Arya.

> “Could you bring back a man without a head?” Arya asked. “Just the once, not six times. Could you?”
>
> “I have no magic, child. Only prayers. That first time, his lordship had a hole right through him and blood in his mouth, I knew there was no hope. So when his poor torn chest stopped moving, I gave him the good god’s own kiss to send him on his way. I filled my mouth with fire and breathed the flames inside him, down his throat to lungs and heart and soul. The last kiss it is called, and many a time I saw the old priests bestow it on the Lord’s servants as they died. I had given it a time or two myself, as all priests must. But never before had I felt a dead man shudder as the fire filled him, nor seen his eyes come open. **It was not me who raised him, my lady. It was the Lord. R’hllor is not done with him yet.** Life is warmth, and warmth is fire, and fire is God’s and God’s alone.”

From this, it is clear that it isn't Thoros that's bringing people back but R'hollor.

Comment: But he did not attempt it? When the Hound killed Berrick, he just bent over and said a few lines and *poof*! Berrick was alive again.

Comment: Because he knows the Lord of Light needed Beric.

Comment: Still, why would R'hllor decide to resurrect Beric several times, but refuse to resurrect anyone during this crucial mission ?

Comment: 1. Pretty pressed for time. 2. Beric states many times. The Lord of Light has a purpose for him.

Comment: @Kepotx if I could answer all these questions with "Because D&D were working with scraps. Run out of money so we could see cool Dragon scenes, and left out a lot" I would. But I can't so this is the canonical answer.

Comment: @Kepotx Not to mention that Thoros himself was BADLY injured and may not have been able to "fill his mouth with fire" to even try.

Comment: despite his injuries, he had no problem filling his mouth with whiskey! @eldothiad, you don't need special effects to revive someone. Just have the actor lie on the floor and then stand up and say "whee! I am alive again!" (unless the Screen Actors Guild has some special Union rule for redshirts)

Comment: @eshier thoros is not the only one who can pass the flame of life

Comment: @Kepotx a) the question is asking about him specifically, b) in the show, only he and Melisandre have done it and she's not there.  I assume you mean what happened in the books with Beric (haven't read them--waiting for them to all be out), but clearly that is a different version of events since Beric is with them and hasn't passed the flame on.

Comment: @eshier you'll be waiting till the day you die.

Comment: @Edlothiad I got burned with Wheel of Time, so going to wait.  There's plenty of other books to read & the show's okay, too.  If I never read them, I'll be alright.

Answer (score 1):

[@Edlothiad's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/167700/58193) answers why it probably wouldn't have worked if he tried but there's also another very obvious reason.

## He's just been mauled by an undead bear

I have a detailed [answer here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/177965/58193) as to who dies and when they die but I'll give the short answer here. The attack of the wight bear is the first time the merry men loses someone and is also the first fight they have. At the end of the fight Thoros is mauled by the bear. After that he needs help walking and his incredibly fragile, indeed dying a few hours later. It's likely he's having trouble concentrating too considering blood loss, even with Beric having cauterised the wound. As such I doubt he even thought about doing it.

Comment: Don't be silly, he's not hurt, he's fine.

Comment: Yeah he had a burning sword held against a gaping chest wound for 2 seconds. He's all better!

Comment: Also I believe their called the "Fellowship of the Wight" not the Merry Men ;)